# get error in for loop's body in java

Tags: java

i want to calculate average of unlimited average but i get error in for loop.
this code must put sumation of paameteres in total variable and out of for loop it calculate average (total/numbers)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(average(1, 5, 6, 87, 7));
}

public static int average(int... numbers) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        total += numbers;
    }
    return total / numbers.length;
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: change ``total += numbers;`` to ``total += numbers[i];``.

Comment: Or even simpler: `for (int n : numbers) total += n;`

Answer (score 4):

first of all, you can't add the **entire** array to the integer total;
it should look like this

```
total += numbers[i];
```

what's not yet a problem, but worth a thought is the following:
if numbers has 0 elements in it, you'll divide by zero in the last line of the average method.

Answer (score 1):

Your **numbers** object is an array

you need to get the integers in every location:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    total += numbers[i];
}
```

another tip:
this here:

```
return total / numbers.length;
```

is a division between integers, you need a double instead!!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add an array to an int. Try this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(average(1, 5, 6, 87, 7));
 }

 public static int average(int... numbers) {
     int total = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
         total += numbers[i];
     }
     return total / numbers.length;
 }
```